# Arguments getting re-assigned

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to strip out the display name from an email, e.g.

`Steve<steve@steve.com>` to `steve@steve.com`

```
    function test1() {
      var testemail = ["Steve<steve@steve.com>","displayname<display@steve.com>"];
  var debug = stripEmail(testemail);

      var debug9 = "";
    }

function stripEmail(email) {
  //Give me an email with a display name and I will strip out the display name
  //"<Steve Gon> stevegon@google.com"
  if (typeof email === 'string') {
    var arr = [email];
  } else {
    var arr = email;
  }

  for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].search("<")>-1) {//If there is no less than, then it doesn't have a display name
      var part1 = arr[i].split("<");
      if (part1.length == 2) {
        arr[i] = part1[1].replace(">","");
        arr[i] = arr[i].replace("<","");
        arr[i] = arr[i].replace(" ","");
      } 
    } 
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Once the code steps out of stripEmail, the argument email is changed to the result. I've notice this happening in some other functions as well. This is resulting in strange problems when I try to use the variables.

Variable testemail set:
[image]

Once I step over the function, testemail is changed.
[image]

Comment: When you pass an array to a function, what's passed is a *reference* to the array. There is no copy made.

Comment: Pointy thanks for the quick response...I guess I am done using W3schools. No explanation of that here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

Comment: W3schools has always been quite a poor and untrustworthy resource. Try MDN instead.

Comment: @SteveGon It _is_ explained under “Objects are Passed by Reference”, though the wording is really poor.

Comment: If you want to test call by value, for example, how about trying like ``var debug = stripEmail(testemail.concat())`` or ``var debug = stripEmail(testemail.slice())``?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid setting one array equal to another array if you want to avoid changing the original array.  Instead of reusing the `email` variable, create a new output variable.  In the code below, the emails are put into a new array named `result`.

The `stripEmail` function handles both a string and an array, and always returns an array that is different than the source array, leaving the original array unchanged.

The code can be changed to:

```
function test1() {
  var testemail = ["Steve<steve@steve.com>","displayname<display@steve.com>"];
  Logger.log('testemail: ' + testemail)

  var debug = stripEmail(testemail);

  Logger.log('debug: ' + debug)
  Logger.log('testemail: ' + testemail)
}

function stripEmail(email) {
  var arr,i,part1,result;

  result = [];

  //Give me an email with a display name and I will strip out the display name
  //"<Steve Gon> stevegon@google.com"
  if (typeof email === 'string') {
    email = email.split(",");
  }

  for (i=0; i<email.length; i++) {
    if (email[i].search("<")>-1) {//If there is no less than, then it doesn't have a display name
      part1 = email[i].split("<");

      if (part1.length == 2) {
        result[i] = part1[1].replace(">","");
        result[i] = result[i].replace("<","");
        result[i] = result[i].replace(" ","");
      } 
    } 
  }

  return result;
}
```